# How to know if a website redirects to other

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php

function ping($host, $port, $timeout) {
    $tB = microtime(true); 
    $fP = fSockOpen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);

    if (!$fP) {
        return "down";
    } 

    $tA = microtime(true); 

    return round((($tA - $tB) * 1000), 0)." ms"; 

}
```

Echoing the result will display either "down" if the host is unreachable or the ping result if it is.

```
echo ping("fernando.ki2.co", 80, 10);

?>
```

I need to write if the ping redirects to a /404.html file. If it doesn't, the subdomain is taken; if it is, the subdomain is free.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Pings only check if a server is alive. Not content available iirc

Comment: `fSockOpen` cannot be "redirected", as it is using IP, not HTTP. Even if you were to use HTTP protocol, you want to watch for the *status* of 404, regardless of what URL the page is redirecting to, as different servers might return different responses on not found.

Answer (score 0):

That way you can't get http status codes.

However, you can use cURL.

`http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php`

It will let PHP directly make an http request to a remote server. After the request is made, you can analyze the returned data, the status code and everything else.

This example shows how to get the status code:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)

echo $http_code;

?>
```

Comment: Even though he calls his function `ping`, it's not doing a real ping. It's opening a TCP connection, not using ICMP Echo.